# Password protect page django

Tags: python, django

I would like to make a registration page for judges, but I would like to make sure that before entering the registration page you have to enter the password, each judge will have the same one that I will make available to them, he needs a simple page with one window to enter the password previously given by me. If someone would be able to say how I can create such a model and then its form, or if there is any other easier way, I will be grateful for any hints

```
class PasswordJudges(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 11)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.password
```

```
class JudgesPassword(forms.ModelForm):
    hasło = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = PasswordJudges
        fields = ['password']
```

but in view a have nothing because everything i wrote was wrong :/

Comment: Can you show some of your existing code? Then we can help show you where you could improve and fix any bugs!

Comment: As a pointer have a look at using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views), when the password is correct you can use sessions to store a value to show that the user has given the correct password. Check for the session before you serve the restricted page.

Comment: @GTBebbo i have something like this

Comment: I agree with @GTBebbo about sessions. Get the password from a form in `views.py`. (Check if `request.method == POST`, then check the form type if using multiple forms, and then check that the form is valid). Afterward, check that the form input for the password matches the correct password (or corresponds to a hash of the correct password) stored in your database. If it's correct, create a session variable indicating that they can view the judges page, redirect to that page, and upon loading that page, check that session variable to see that they used the right password

Comment: @bug_spray i have one more question, have can i grab this singel field from the model, just password that I set up ?

Answer (score 4):

I decided to make this a full answer for clarity. You could do something like the following:

In views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import JudgesForm
from .models import JudgeDetail

def home_view(request):
    # Initiate your form
    judge_form = JudgesForm(request.POST or None)

    # Initiate your session variable
    request.session['judge_password'] = 'invalid'

    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        if judge_form.is_valid():
            user = judge_form.cleaned_data['user']
            password = judge_form.cleaned_data['password']

            try:
                # get the actual password info from the database
                user_object = JudgeDetail.objects.filter(username=user).get()
                actual_pw = user_object.password
                if (actual_pw == password):
                    request.session['judge_password'] = 'valid'
                    return redirect('judge_view')
                else:
                    return redirect('home_view')
            except:
                # handle exceptions here

    home_context = {
    # put context stuff here
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", home_context)

def judge_view(request):
    if (request.session['judge_password'] != 'valid'):
        return redirect('home_view')

    # ...

    judge_context = {
    # ...
    }

    return render(request, "judge.html", judge_context)
```

In models.py

```
from django.db import models

class JudgeDetail(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import JudgeDetail

class JudgesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = JudgeDetail
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

---

*Optional*: You may wish to store a hashed version of passwords in the database for users, instead of storing the actual passwords, so that someone with admin privileges can't see everyone's password. If you do this, simply do `password = hash_function(password)` before storing or comparing passwords, where `hash_function()` is whatever hash function you choose to use.