# Creating a double log in system for department and user

Tags: python, django, django-login

I'm using django to create an webapp. I have been asked if I can look at creating a sort of double log in system.

For example: A nurse on the ward will open up my webapp and will be met with a login page for their ward. So all nurses on that ward will have that generic log in.

Once they've logged in they will be met with a second login page where they can enter their normal user credentials that only they know.

I'm quite stuck at how to achieve this currently - or if someone could suggest an alternative method I'd be grateful!

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708824/password-protect-page-django . Beyond this, an older method that is non-django specific is to use .htaccess for protecting certain pages

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend authenticating the user normally, then use some property of that user (maybe a permissions group etc.) to represent the ward they belong too.  Then it follows to restrict that user to information/pages relevant to their ward